Plot python in VSCode *without Jupyter*
I make a new file with the following contents, run it, and see no output. I know that I can put it in a cell with #%% but I don't like using Jupyter notebooks. Is there really no way for me to see the plot  in VSCode without saving it to a file? It's possible in Julia.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 20, 100)
plt.plot(x, np.sin(x))
plt.show()

I also tried executing these lines in REPL but plotting does not work either (the figure is created but not displayed).
It might be relevant that I am working on a remote machine. I ssh to my school server using VSCode.

Since you are SSH'ing into your school server, the graph is generated, and is displayed on the server. Since you probably only have command-line access, you are unable to see it.

Since you are SSH'ing into your school server, the graph is generated, and is displayed on the server. Since you probably only have command-line access, you are unable to see it.

Make sure you are using X11 redirection for SSH. In OpenSSH that should be the -X argument or ForwardX11 yes in the config file.

This question is similar to: Matplotlib: display plot on a remote machine. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

In Julia I can see the plot right in vscode, without any forwarding. But not in Python. It's not true that I only have command line access, because I use Vscode to ssh to the server.

You are running the code on a remote server. The plot will be shown on the "remote server display" instead of your local machine. To display the image on local you will need to enable X11 forwarding when connecting to your school server:
ssh -X <your_school_server>.
Note that the SSH daemon on computer A will also have to be configured to enable X11 forwarding. This is done by putting
X11Forwarding yes
in computer A's sshd_config configuration file.
If School Server's SSH daemon does not have X11 forwarding enabled, you can always have Python write the result of the calculation to a text file, download it to your machine, and use Matplotlib locally.
